# How do I add different option_settings for different elastic beanstalk environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to add a different `NODE_ENV` environment variable using `option_settings` in `.ebextensions` for different elastic beanstalk environments ie,

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: NODE_ENV
    value: production
```

where `value` is `staging` or `production` depending on 2 different elastic beanstalk environments I have (which are also mapped to different git branches as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html)

Is it possible to do it in `.ebextenions`? Or do I need access the management console?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to do this in .ebextensions if you have diferent packages per environment.   With a single package you would have to set this in runtime using the management console, CLI or SDK.

Comment: What would be an example of the files I would have to add for the 2 different environments?

Comment: What i mean is that the only to do this using these static .config files is to have two packages with different values in that file. For example, you may have options.production and options.development and, at build time, you copy them to the final options.config. Usually this is not a good idea, so you'd better set up your env. vars using the console, cli or sdk.

Comment: If you are using eb client you can also try using `eb branch` which allows you to maintain different values in different git branches: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-branch-environment.html